# Unable to save changes to dataset

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, dataset, datasource

I have a dataSource added to my C# project, it only has a few columns and the user will be inputting data and adding rows to the database, and will also be able to search for certain rows. I am unable to save any changes. The changes appear in my `DataGridView` when I press the add button but when I re-start my program (I built and exported it btw, not in debug mode) the changes from before are not there. Why is this?

```
 //called when the new entry button is clicked, adds new row into DB
    private void CreatEnrtyBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Create new row to construct
        BettingDB1DataSet.HorsesRow row = bettingDB1DataSet.Horses.NewHorsesRow();

        //Add values to row
        row.HorseName = this.HorseNameBox.Text;
        row.Trainer = this.TrainerNameBox.Text;
        row.Place = this.PlaceBox.Text;
        row.Location = this.LocationBox.Text;
        row.Jockey = this.JockeyNameBox.Text;
        row.Track = this.LocationBox.Text;
        row.Ground = "temp";

        //Add row to DB and commit changes
        bettingDB1DataSet.Horses.AddHorsesRow(row);

        //tried both of these on their own, but neither work?
        horsesTableAdapter.Update(bettingDB1DataSet.Horses);
        horsesTableAdapter.Update(row);
    }
```

How horsesTableAdapter is created, as requested:

```
        private BettingDB1DataSetTableAdapters.HorsesTableAdapter horsesAdapter;


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'bettingDB1DataSet2.Horses' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.horsesTableAdapter.Fill(this.bettingDB1DataSet2.Horses);
        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = bettingDB1DataSet.Horses;

    }
```

Comment: Do you get any exceptions, or do the method just complete normally, with no change to the database?

Comment: Everything goes well. Row appears in the dataGrid, Primary-key is auto-added and everything. But when the program is open again no changes were saved.

Comment: @silent The problem you're describing is that nothing is *loaded* into the grid after you restart the program. Have you actually verified that nothing was changed in the DB itself?

Comment: @Rshepp MS SQL sever File I believe. And BartoszKP the grid view in my form sees the changes instantly and displays the new row, the problem is when I close the program and open it again, the grid does not have the changes anymore. So on first run my grid has no rows, I add a couple using this button and it displays the added rows. I close the program and open it again and I am back to having no more rows.

Comment: Yes it is local. No server connections here :). Right, then if that is the case how would I go about stopping this? Used to doing 50-line Python scripts so this is all a little over-whelming ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You fill bettingDB1DataSet2 with your dataadapter.
2. You grid datasource call bettingDB1DataSet.
3. You are updating bettingDB1DataSet.

Maybe this is the problem.

Comment: This seems to be the cause, my project hass gotten a little messy so I'm going to re-do it taking everyone's help into account. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you accept dataset changes before update???.

bettingDB1DataSet.Acceptchanges();
        horsesTableAdapter.Update(bettingDB1DataSet.Horses);

Comment: I tried this earlier and it did nothing, I also read that AcceptChanges() marks edited rows as non-edited so if I call this before Update() then it will not know that the rows need saving?

Comment: Can you show how you create your horsesTableAdapter?